# what is the difference between Managed Application & Web Based Application?

Tags: web-applications

I want to know the difference between managed application & web based application. I am developing smart device application in .NET. Can we differentiate ASP.NET, C#.NET, VB.NET application based on difference between Managed Application & Web based application?

Comment: What do you mean by "managed application"? Can you post a link to some kind of definition? If we are talking "managed code", it's not something you can compare to "web based application".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are orthogonal concepts.

Managed refers to applications that run on a virtual machine, like Java and .NET, who manage memory allocation etc. As opposed to unmanaged applications, that run on top of the host OS.

Web based applications refer to 3-tier applications (typically browser-appserver-DB). Contrast them with your typical Winforms applications that entirely runs on the client making requests to a remote DB.

Answer (score 1):

The two terms are unrelated: managed refers to a garbage collection memory model; web based means an application runs under a server which responds to web requests.

For instance, an ASP.NET web application is both.

Answer (score 0):

Managed code, is a type of executable that runs within a virtual machine, rather than as native machine code.  A web based application can be either managed or native, so this is a false dichotomy I'm afraid.